# Submitting Form with Selenium by Clicking on the Send Button puts all Settings back in the DOM Tree

Tags: c#, selenium, dom, selenium-chromedriver, surveymonkey

I am using `Selenium` with `.NET`. 
The WebDriver I am using is `ChromeDriver`.

I wrote a code, which fills a simple form (survey; from surveymonkey.com). The DOM Tree gets changed (manipulated) perfectly as I want it to. 
But as soon as I click the `button` to submit the data (the survey/form), I get an error from the survey page, i.e. “please answer the question(s) x,y,...,n.” I verified the `DOM Tree` after getting this error, and amazingly, the `DOM Tree` has changed back to default, as there was never a change, except to the `Input` and `TextArea` Fields – these two nodes have been accepted from the page (the manipulation from `selenium` to the `TextArea` and `Input` Fields were accepted). So all manipulation on the `Radio Buttons` and `Checkboxes` has changed back to unchecked when clicking on the `send button`.

What I did: 
I set a `breakpoint` before clicking on the button, copied the `DOM Tree` and compared that one with the `DOM Tree` of a real client: There was no difference except on the `meta node` (some `query parameters` of a script).
So I was really confused, why the survey won't work with selenium but with a real client, even though the DOM Tree are the same.
Therefore, I tried it with another Driver (with `IE` and `Firefox`) - I had the exact same problem.

Since the DOM Tree are the same (selenium and real client), I think there is a problem with the selenium Click event? Btw, I also tried, instead of `Click()`, to submit the form by `Keys.Enter` - it did not work as well.

Here is the `link` of the survey (to get the `DOM Tree`): https://de.surveymonkey.com/r/KZDWJD2?pharmacy=test

Example: For the `Radio buttons`, what I did (and the only thing which is necessary) was changing/manipulating the attribute `aria-checked` from `false` to `true`. As soon as I submitted the survey, this attribute changes back to `false`, which seems really strange to me and therefore cannot be send to the backend (message in the frontend: 'please answer the question 1,2,...,n).

Here is some code from my `C#`: 
Changing the above attribute: `

```
public static void SetAttribute(this IWebElement webElement, string name, string value)
        {
            var driver = ((IWrapsDriver)webElement).WrappedDriver;
            var jsExecutor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
            jsExecutor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].setAttribute(arguments[1], arguments[2]);", webElement, name, value);
        }
```

As already mentioned, the attribute gets changed perfectly by above method. But, as soon as selenium submits the survey (by clicking on the button), the `attribute` gets changed back to `false` and the survey can therefore not be sent.

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add code trial, HTML snippet and Error stack trace. Thanks

Comment: @NarendraR Thank you for your comment. I Updated my post - thank you in advance for your/any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging I found out, that survey monkey adds another attribute to every input field: `checked="checked"` - adding this attribute to the specific node elements was the key to the solution - the survey can now be sent.